# A particular complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Whats is the name for a complexity like $n^{\log \log n}$ ? Is this exactly subexponential, or less than that ?

Answer (score 7):

It is quasi-polynomial time. See it under examples http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity